# What am I doing wrong with action url in my form

Tags: django, forms, url, action

I am trying to do search method in my_app.
Code in my **navbar.html** is as below. It is not full code.
The other buttons in the navbar work fine.
These are not forms - just regular links.

```
<form class="d-flex" action="{% url 'search_record' %}" method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input class="form-control me-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

In my **urls.py** I have name "search_record"

```
urlpatterns = [
path('show/', show_record, name="show_record"),
path('new/', new_record, name="new_record"),
path('edit/<int:id>/', edit_record, name="edit_record"),
path('del/<int:id>/', delete_record, name="delete_record"),
path('search_record/', search_record, name="search_record")]
```

I have the appropriate entries in the file **views.py**

```
def search_record(request):
return render(request, 'my_app/search_record.html', 
    {})
```

And I also have a template file search_record.html in the directory templates/my_app whose content is as follows:

```
{% extends 'my_app/index.html' %}
{% block title %} Search Results {% endblock %}

{% block page %}
    <h1>Results ...</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

When I am using the url: **http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/search_record/** in the browser then  search_record.html works good it shows me "**Results ...**", but clicking the **Search** button in the navbar does't work. After clicking this button, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong ?
I have django 4 in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think change button type to submit cause you are submitting form on clicking that button